# javascript How I want to add data to my desired location in array?

Tags: javascript

I want to put the data in the desired location. I want to add values ​​in the array. But I have no idea how to deserve this. Please advise me!

for example,I'll put in the second position data.

before

```
var arr=["1","2","3"];
```

after

```
var arr=["1","2","@","3"];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for the `.splice()` method for arrays. Read about it [here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_splice.asp).

For your example, it would be something like

`arr.splice(2,0,'@')`

This says "go to element 2 of the array, remove 0 elements, and add the element '@'".